# scroll last Cell to top of UITableView

Tags: dynamic, uitableview, contentsize

on my last cell is a dynamic textview. With bigger contentSize it will be stay on top of the tableview (to see it, while you fill it on keyboard), but if the textview and also the cell is going to be dynamically bigger: [tableview beginupdates] and [tableview endUpdates] will delete my contentSize. And after that it is scrolling it down to bottom of tableview.

Any ideas how to scroll the cell to the top, and create the cell also dynamically without changes on contentSize? maybe I'm thinking on the right way, ideas?

**EDIT**

Hmm..not any "correct" solution found...the best way for this purpose is to try set any new cells or sections below the textview to get this cell easy to top of the view. After this its easy to use it with beginUpdates and endUpdates. The cursor will be always in the textview, textview will be dynamically bigger also the cell, so the only easy way.

Another option is to set the uitableview as a subview of another scrollview (uitableview himself has one) to scroll up an down in the new scrollview.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Text views in cells is a very tricky issue. I recommend just using the free Sensible TableView framework, which has text view cells available out of the box.